# Affine space terminology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

I am wondering about the terminology "affine space" in algebraic geometry. As I understand it, given a basis field $k$, the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ is simply the space of n-tuples $k^n.$

I know the general definition of an affine space (i.e. a set which admits a transitive and free vector space action).  So I'm guessing that the decision to relabel $k^n$ as $\mathbb{A}^n$ is meant to indicate that elements of this space should not be added, subtracted, ect. Is this indeed the case?

(As an aside, differential geometers often seem to write $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\mathbb{E}^n.$ I have always assumed that this was meant to emphasize that $\mathbb{R}^n$ should be viewed as a vector space but rather as a smooth manifold which does not a priori admit a vector space structure.)

Comment: Yes, your guess is right: the idea is that the vector space structure on $k^n$ is irrelevant to algebraic geometry. (One of the standard books says this right at the start, but I can't seem to find it just now.) Another, fancier, reason is that at some stage of developing algebraic geometry, it becomes convenient to think about algebraic varieties as more than just "the sum of their points". (What I am really talking about here is _schemes_.) From this point of view $\mathbf A^n$ has a lot more to it than just the points of $k^n$.

Comment: @Asal I think Harris' book says this at the start.

Comment: @Hoot: ah, the one I didn't check! :)

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: I have not yet studied schemes seriously, just briefly flirted with them. But i am curious: these extra points of $\mathbb{A}^n$, do they have an actual geometric meaning, or are they just an artifact of the construction of schemes for the purpose of obtaining a tight correspondence between spectra of rings and points of "varieties"?

Comment: @Manos: the extra points are certainly geometric --- they are the exactly the _generic points_ of irreducible varieties of $\mathbf A^n$. Hartshorne discusses this (with one of his few pictures) somewhere in Chapter II, soon after he defines schemes.